# Sleuth with Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have the following functional style topology:

```
1) KStream input
2) filter
3) flapMap
4) aggregate
5) filter
6) map
7) KStream output
```

The input KStream comes with sleuth headers, but they get lost in the kafka stream.
FlapMap split one record into N Records.
I need every output record has same sleuth headers that the input record.

```
Dependency Versions:

spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.0.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.1.RELEASE
```

I have read the official documentation and some articles like https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/10/distributed-tracing-with-kafka-streams/
but I need to know what is the right way to do this.

thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1363 and specifically this comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1363#issuecomment-525455291

Comment: it seems that it still has no support ??

Comment: Please feel free to create a GH issue in the Kafka binder repository and provide details with your use case. We can take it from there.

Comment: thx. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/826